# Debug a MPI code with Cmakefile in visual studio code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, mpi

I am trying to debug an open-source C code with MPI. This  open-source has it own Cmakefile. I enable the mpi and debug model with the  instructions of the open-source in the terminal. After the executable file named gmx_mpi is created, I import the project to visual studio code. I can run the executable file in terminal with below command

```
mpirun -np 4 gmx_mpi mdrun -s diff.tpr -c diff.gro -ntomp 1
```

So I made below configurations to debug the code with MPI in the visual studio code.

```json
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/usr/bin/mpirun",
    "args": [
        "-np",
        "4",
        "/home/fanli/workspace/gromacs_fh_debug/build/bin/gmx_mpi",
        "mdrun",
        "-s",
        "diff.tpr",
        "-deffnm",
        "diff",
        "-ntomp",
        "1"
    ],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "/home/fanli/workspace/protein_water/double/40ms",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the code did not stop at the breakpoint I set, instead it run directly as if the it is in the release mode.

I googled a lot but did not find the solution.

Could anyone tell me how to debug the MPI code in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot debug MPI code in vs code automatically and there is no extension to do so. See the issue below on GitHub for any change or update

[GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1723)

However, I found a workaround to duplicate the vs code window and attach the debugger manually:

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTt02xuD51w)